# How to change data in Fragment for View pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a view pager with only one fragment.
I am doing this as the basic layout of the page would remain the same, only some of the details like text view and images would change and so I am re-using the same fragment for each 
page in the view pager.

The question is that where and how do i pass the information to the fragment that I am currently on so and so page (ex: page#3). once the fragment has this information, it would be able to adjust its view/layout and display the following information.

could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener where in your onPageSelected method you can get the selected page/fragment with the position parameter. When you get the fragment you can call any public method you want in your fragment.

Comment: small example would be appreciated for getting the fragment via position. thanks

Comment: check tycj's answer if that helps i was thinking a bit differently but almost that same.Nevertheless it should help. Also can you post your fragmentpageradaptor here to see clearly how it should done?

Comment: By the way if you are using support library do not use getFragmentManager() use getSupportFragmentManager() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add fragment dynamically into your viewpager use this way:

```
 class ParentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public ParentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
            ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((MYFragment)this.fragments.get(position)).updateLayout();
    }

}
```

Attach instance of adapter as ViewPager's OnPageChangeListener(). 
Like this `mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(myParentPagerAdapter);`

Comment: ok so if i have the lisntener in  the adaptor itself, then i could do persist the instance of the fragment to change...let me try that out..

Comment: ok but the problem is that i am using a tab host with the view pager so i need the adaptor listener in the activity that handles the tab host so that the current tab could also be changed when the page is changed

Comment: are you trying to do something like this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator. Also you can solve your current problem within the scope of our solution.Since you have handle of the tabhost in your activity you can implement a public class like setCurrentSelectedTab(int postion). Where from onPageSelected method call ((MYActivity)getActivity).setCurrentSelectedTab(position)).

Comment: yup that makes sense. actually i just did it the other way around. i had a public method in my adaptor for getting the current fragment. now from my activity i just get that fragment and change it accordingly. any comments about this?

Comment: one problem has many solutions :) use the one that best fit for you

Answer (score 0):

either keep an instance of the fragment once you create it or use

```
MyFragment myFrag = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(r.id.myfragment);
```

to get the fragment by its id

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int currentPage) {
            MyFragment myFrag = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(r.id.myfragment);
            myFrag.updateLayout(currentPage);
        }

    });
```

Comment: how will this help. i want to change data in the fragment based on the page number?

Comment: create a public method in the fragment to change the layout then use the instance of myFrag to update based on the page number. ie. myFrag.updateLayout(pageNum);

Comment: so u mean inside fragmentpageradaptor, inside getItem(), I get the frag instance that is being turned to. then change the layout and then finally return that fragment from the getItem() function? Also, i am now fragment in the layout, I am instantiating it at run time... so how do i get the current fragment? thanks

Comment: thank you very much..very helpful. one question though...Also, i do not have the fragment in the layout, I am instantiating it at run time... so how do i get the current fragment. so wht id do i specify

Comment: just keep an instance of the fragment when you create it

Comment: but the instance would be in the adaptor and onpagechangelistner would be called from the activity?

Comment: use child classes and have a class wide instance of the fragment to use where ever